# Resolution of NSURL bookmark fails for an external drive in Yosemite

Tags: cocoa, usb, nsurl, security-scoped-bookmarks

In my cocoa app I use the following code to create a security-scoped bookmark from an NSURL that I got from an NSOpenPanel:

```
NSData *bookmarkData=[myURL bookmarkDataWithOptions:([NSURL instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(startAccessingSecurityScopedResource)] ? NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope : 0) includingResourceValuesForKeys:(&NSURLPathKey==NULL ? [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLVolumeIsLocalKey,nil] : [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLPathKey,NSURLVolumeIsLocalKey,nil]) relativeToURL:nil error:&error];
```

and to resolve it, I use:

```
BOOL isStale;
myURL=[NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmarkData options:options relativeToURL:nil bookmarkDataIsStale:&isStale error:nil];
```

In Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9), this works fine when I create a bookmark for an external drive, like a USB stick. But in Yosemite (10.10), if the external drive is not mounted, the bookmark resolution doesn't return `nil` as it does in Mavericks. Instead, it returns a url that points to Macintosh HD (i.e. `[myURL path]` returns the string `@"/"`). I noticed that in this case `isStale==YES`.

Does somebody else experienced the same problem? Is this a known bug in Yosemite or am I missing some additional step to handle such a case? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug seems to be resolved in Mac OS X El Capitan.